# Manipulating google maps marker position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this basic map straight from the docs

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
  });

  var image = 'images/beachflag.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
```

and produces this https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/icon-simple

I want to move the marker some pixels up or down of its current position visually on the map and not moving it by some coordinates.

I would also like to tilt the marker at some point. Does the api allow one to manipulate the marker in ways i have described?.

Comment: Can I ask why you want the marker to not mark what it is supposed to?

Comment: I am more interested in the tilting of the marker but if i can move it a few pixels,that would be an added advantage. I am building a hiking app and if the actual position is off by a few metres,thats acceptable.

Comment: See my answer mate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the size, origin and anchor of a custom image marker using something like

```
var image = {
    url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,32)
};
```

By setting the `origin` and `anchor` parameters, you can shift your marker icon by some pixels in any direction. For tilting your marker, you can just produce another PNG image with the tilted marker image and replace the icon of your marker.

See the [complex icon marker example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) in the Google Maps Javascript API documentation for a more thorough information.

Comment: 0,32 looks like a point on the Cartesian plane. Does it imply 32 pixels north(i.e +ve)  of origin?

Comment: The coordinates of the `anchor` parameter are with respect to the image coordinates, where (0, 0) is on top left. With an image of 20x32 pixels, coordinate (0, 32) is bottom left (the base of the flagpole).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at creating your own marker as a trans .png with a gap at the bottom or top? And you can just rotate the image as you like when creating the png.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

**EDIT**

See @chkaiser answer about adding origin and anchor, probs better than leaving gap at top or bottom ;-)